Showing or refuting that $\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{t|\xi|}}\,d\xi\leq \frac{1}{t}$
Is true that, for some $R>0$ (big enough)$, \int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{t|\xi|}}\,d\xi\leq \frac{1}{t}$ for any $t>0$?
My attempt: Let $s>n$. The exponential function is faster than any polynomial, so, $t(1+|\xi|)^{s/n}\leq \mathrm{e}^{t|\xi|}$ for all $|\xi|>R$, for some $R>0$.
Then
\begin{align}
\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{t |\xi|}}\,d\xi&\leq \frac{1}{t}\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|)^{s/n}}\,d\xi\\
&\leq \frac{1}{t}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{1}{(1+|\xi|)^{s}}\,d\xi
\end{align}
and the last integral is convergente when $s>n$.
Is this method correct?

Is there a reason to why you think your method is not correct?

a little because $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\xi}},d\xi$ doesn't converges and this caused me some confusion

$R$ depends on $t$ at $t(1+|\xi|)^{s/n} \leq e^{t|\xi|}$.

why do  not compute explicitely the integral $I=\int_{\|\xi\|>R}e^{-t\|\xi\|}d\xi$? Just use polar coordinates $\xi=\rho \theta$ where $\theta$  is on the unit sphere $S_{n-1}.$  We get $d\xi=d\theta\times \rho^{n-1}d\rho$.   If $C_n$ is the area of $S_{n-1}$ we get
$$I=C_n\int_R^{\infty}e^{-t\rho}\rho^{n-1}d\rho=C_n\frac{1}{t^n}\int_{tR}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx$$ Now we use for $y>0$
$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{y}^{\infty}e^{-x}x^{n-1}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-y}\frac{y^k}{k!}<1$$ (take derivative in $y$ of both sides to check it) and we get finally
$$I=C_ne^{-tR}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}R^k\times \frac{(n-1)!}{k!}\frac{1}{t^{n-k}}<C_n\frac{(n-1)!}{t^n}.$$

In which book could I find this or similar problems? I am referring to changes of variables over the space $\mathbb{R}^n$. I find the arguments for changes of variables interesting.

I have been teaching measure theory without textbooks as they do in France, using folklore for several tricks.  The proof I was giving that the image of the Lebesgue measure $dx$ on the Euclidean space $R^n$  by the map $x\mapsto \frac{x}{|x|},|x|=(\theta,\rho)$ is $d\theta \times \rho^{n-1}d\rho$ was done by computing $\int_{R^n}e^{-s|x|^2}dx$ in two ways: using $|x|^2=x_1^2+cdots+x_n^2$ or doing the above change of variable. Book? Gerard Letac, Integration, Probability and Fourier Analysis, Exercises, Springer 1996. The corresponding textbook was from Paul Malliavin.

It is not correct: let $R > 0$ be fixed. Then it is by substitution $x = t\xi$ for all $t > 0$
$\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{e^{t|\xi|}}d\xi = \frac{1}{t^n}\int_{|x|>Rt} e^{-|x|}dx \leq \frac{1}{t}$ if and only if $\int_{|x|>Rt} e^{-|x|}dx \leq t^{n-1}$ for all $t>0$. If $n \geq 2$ it immediately yields to a contradiction $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|}dx = 0$ (by $t \to 0$).
For $n = 1$:
But
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-|x|}dx = 2\int_0^\infty  e^{-r}dr = 2\cdot 1 = 2$$
So the best upper bound in case $n = 1$ would be
$$\int_{|\xi|>R}\frac{1}{e^{t|\xi|}}d\xi \leq \frac{2}{t}.$$

How $1/t$ appears in the last inequality? Is it because $t|\xi|=|t\xi|$?

@eraldcoil yes. Substitution as in the first paragraph.

But shouldn't it be $1/t^n$ instead of $1/t$? Am I miscalculating

@eraldcoil yes sorry, I have corrected. It makes it even worse.
